# Casting smallint to boolean in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting

I am trying to cast a smallint to a boolean in PostgreSQL. This does not work out of the box, for example:

```
select (1::smallint)::bool;
```

returns "ERROR: 42846: cannot cast type smallint to boolean"

I can fix this using:

```
select (1::smallint)::int::bool;
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way I can define how to cast `smallint` directly to `boolean`?

The reason for this is that I (and others that I work with) have summary queries which cast an `int` column from a database table to `boolean`. I would like to change this column to `smallint`, but doing so would brake this logic because there is no direct cast from `smallint` to `boolean`. Is it possible to use the postgres `CREATE CAST` to define how to cast a `smallint` to a `boolean`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION boolean1(i smallint) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    BEGIN
            RETURN (i::smallint)::int::bool;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE CAST (smallint AS boolean) WITH FUNCTION boolean1(smallint) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

Answer (score 14):

I was trying:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycol TYPE bool USING mycol::bool;
```

using the same approach as "Ispirer SQLWays Migrations"'s answer (cast smallint to int and then to boolean) worked:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycol TYPE bool USING mycol::int::bool;
```